# How to add a row number based on criteria in SAS Enterprise Studio?

Tags: sas

I have a table like this:

```
ID      OLD_ACCOUNT    NEW_ACCOUNT  DATE        OTHER_DATE
20      001            002          1/1/2023    1/1/2023
20      002            003          2/1/2023    2/1/2023
20      002            004          4/1/2023    2/1/2023
20      003            004          4/1/2023    4/1/2023
30      101            102          1/2/2023    1/2/2023
30      102            103          2/2/2023    2/2/2023
```

I am trying to add a row number that starts at 1 at the first iteration of a new "OTHER_DATE" for each unique "ID".  So the new column would look like this:

```
ID      OLD_ACCOUNT    NEW_ACCOUNT  DATE        OTHER_DATE   COUNT
20      001            002          1/1/2023    1/1/2023     1
20      002            003          2/1/2023    2/1/2023     1
20      002            004          4/1/2023    2/1/2023     2
20      003            004          4/1/2023    4/1/2023     1
30      101            102          1/2/2023    1/2/2023     1
30      102            103          2/2/2023    2/2/2023     1
```

This is the code I tried:

```
data add_row_count ;
set LIB.Table1;
count + 1;
by ID DATE OTHER_DATE;
if first.OTHER_DATE then count = 1;
run;
```

This is returning a 1 for every row which is not what I need.  Thank you in advance

Comment: Are those DMY or MDY strings you have in your date variables? Are they actual date variables or character strings?

Comment: They are date variables. In the Format 01JAN2015

Comment: So numeric variables with SAS date values with the DATE9. format attached so they print in the style 01JAN2015.

Comment: Instead of naming the variable `COUNT` I recommend using something like `seq` (sequence number) or `other_date_index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove DATE from the BY list.

```
data have ;
  input ID $ OLD_ACCOUNT $ NEW_ACCOUNT $ DATE OTHER_DATE;
  informat date other_date ddmmyy.;
  format date other_date yymmdd10.;
cards;
20 001 002 1/1/2023 1/1/2023
20 002 003 2/1/2023 2/1/2023
20 002 004 4/1/2023 2/1/2023
20 003 004 4/1/2023 4/1/2023
30 101 102 1/2/2023 1/2/2023
30 102 103 2/2/2023 2/2/2023
;

data want;
  set have;
  by id other_date;
  count+1;
  if first.other_date then count=1;
run;
```

Result

```
              OLD_       NEW_
Obs    ID    ACCOUNT    ACCOUNT          DATE    OTHER_DATE    count

 1     20      001        002      2023-01-01    2023-01-01      1
 2     20      002        003      2023-01-02    2023-01-02      1
 3     20      002        004      2023-01-04    2023-01-02      2
 4     20      003        004      2023-01-04    2023-01-04      1
 5     30      101        102      2023-02-01    2023-02-01      1
 6     30      102        103      2023-02-02    2023-02-02      1
```

Comment: I get an error that the By variables are not properly sorted on the data set "have"

Comment: Do you want to sort the data first?  Otherwise if you want to process the data in its current order and the data is not sorted add the NOTSORTED keyword to the BY statement to tell the data step that fact.  If that does not work then you need to update your example to have records that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: That did it! The data is already sorted so adding the NOTSORRTED keyword and removing the DATE from the sort worked!

Answer (score 0):

Order of operations possibly. How does this work for you?

```
data add_row_count ;
set LIB.Table1;
by ID DATE OTHER_DATE;
if first.OTHER_DATE then count = 1;
else count+1;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But, I am still getting the same result. All 1s